# Playing an alert sound when the phone is on vibrate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I have my app running in the background polling an email server and sending a local notification when there is a change. I'm able to start playing the alert from a background state, but if the phone is on vibrate, the audio will not play. Is there a way to override that, kind of how the clock app's alarm still sounds when vibrate is on?

In my app delegate on launch, I call my alert's class method below to set up for playing in the background:

```
+ (void)initializeAudioSettings
{
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error setting up Audio session: %@", setCategoryError.description);
    }

    NSError *activationError = nil;
    success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error setting audio session active: %@", activationError.description);
    }

}
```

Next I load the alert:

```
- (void)loadAlertSoundID
{
    NSLog(@"Loading alert sound");
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"alert" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL URLWithString:soundPath];

    CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL;

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(url, &_alertSoundID);
}
```

Then when I'm notified of a new message, I call my alert method:

```
- (void)playAlert
{
    NSLog(@"Playing alert");
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_alertSoundID);

    _alertShouldBePlaying =  YES;
    _alertIsPlaying = YES;

    AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(_alertSoundID, nil, nil, playSoundFinished, (__bridge void*)self);

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(vibrate:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

And for completion, my completion block.:

```
void playSoundFinished (SystemSoundID sound, void *data)
{
    Alert *alert = [Alert sharedAlert];
    if (sound == alert.alertSoundID)
    {
        alert.alertIsPlaying = NO;

        // Repeat until alert is disabled
        if (alert.alertShouldBePlaying && !alert.alertIsPlaying)
        {
            [alert playAlert];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the "Get me thrown out of the theater" feature?

Comment: I'm building this as a tool to use internally in the office. There's an option to go "off duty" which switches exclusively to vibrating and then goes back on duty automatically the next day when work starts.

Comment: The whole point of putting a phone on vibrate is to it doesn't make sounds.

Comment: I'm aware, but like I said, this is for internal use and not going to the app store. There has to be a way to do it, because the clock app does exactly this

Comment: Just because an Apple app can do something doesn't mean it is possible for 3rd party app using public APIs. The clock app can update its icon too but 3rd party apps can't do that.

Comment: But it means there are private APIs that can be exposed which I'm  currently sifting through. I came to SO for help of other devs and hackers that might have wanted to bypass this as well, not to be told the obvious fact that it's not part of their public API

Comment: Chris is right - he may be writing an Enterprise app that doesn't have to meet the standards of the app store, nor go through Apple's vetting process.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this but if I were a user of your app I would not appreciate this.

Take a look at [AVAudioSessionCategory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/avfoundation/reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories). You can set your AVAudioSession.category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` or `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` and that will bypass the silent switch on the phone as well as any alert sound settings. It may still be governed by the volume buttons though.

**EDIT:** You will also want to use `AVAudioPlayer` or `AudioUnit` to play sound as opposed to `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` in order to bypass silent mode.

Comment: I already had it set to playback, and I just tried playAndRecord, but it's still silent when it comes in

Comment: Right, I should've read your entire post. You're playing your sound through the AudioServicesPlaySystemSound method. If you use an AVAudioPlayer or the lower level AudioUnit API, you can bypass silent mode. I don't believe AudioServicesPlaySystemSound respects your AVAudioSessionCategory.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the insight. I'm gonna look into AudioUnit and see what I can do with that

Comment: For your purpose, AVAudioPlayer should do the trick, AudioUnit is a bit overkill for just playing a simple sound

Comment: I had started with AVAudioPlayer, but my issue was it wouldn't start playing when the app is in the background. I could only start playing in the foreground and transfer to the background while it was playing

Comment: Yes, that is default iOS behaviour to prevent apps from yelling at you from the background. There's ways around it but I reckon they will get you rejected from the App Store, for good reason.